# IRB String Output Mismatch

Tags: ruby, irb

When I enter my name which contains turkish characters in irb as a string input, irb prints out to terminal as if there is an encoding mismatch. However, if the string is printed to console via puts or print, the output is exactly is what I expected.

What happens here? Is there any way to configure irb so that it shows the string content as if it is printed with puts method.

[image: irb commands]

Answer (score 2):

Using `p my_name` is same as doing `puts my_name.inspect`, where `inspect` returns (in this case) a string with special characters escaped.

Comment: But according the the OP's description, the OP gets the same result with `puts` or `print`. If that is true, then this answer cannot explain that.

Comment: @sawa The difference between `puts` and `print` is `puts` adds a new line. From the screenshot, I see that there is a new line added when using `puts`.

Comment: How does that explain that the string is escaped with `puts` and `print`?

Comment: @sawa Sorry, correct me if I'm wrong. I may be misunderstanding. When initially setting `my_name`, I believe the return statement will return the printable version/[inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-inspect). Similar to how new classes are instantiated, the return statement is the class unique code and instance variables and their values. Using `inspect` on a class will show the same. Using `puts` on a class will not show its instance variables and values. But when using `puts` or `print`, the string gets evaluated, converting escaped characters, like `print "\n"`.

Comment: I can't find it in the docs unfortunately, but just testing via irb, that is what I found. Again, if I didn't answer your question, sorry, I misunderstood.